# How to grow an avocado successfully from seed

Tags: germination, avocado

I have tried half a dozen times to get an avocado pit to grow. Does anyone have a secret I don't for how to sprout this obtuse seed?!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to germinate avocado seed in soil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YM__DWPxxXk)

I think the main problems would be using distilled water versus tap water and making sure the seed has the wide end in the water not the narrow end in the water.[growing avocado seeds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_TbSUSejVk)  You can also try a moist paper towel in a ziplock (I've never tried this with avocado but this is how I start my larger seeds for everything else).  Once the seed is rooted and starts to show the upper growth put it in a 4" pot with potting soil, drainage hole, bottom of pot lifted off surface or saucer with tiles or pot feet, water should only be distilled water not tap water!  (too many chemicals and salts for potted plants)...(for us humans to be drinking)!!!  Roots grown in water are not roots grown in soil.  Germinating in water is fine, but don't allow your seed to become too accustomed to living in water!